# SQLite show data from two tables listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a listview with data from one table, and i need to show in this case: data, value and name, but the column name is in a second table. The first table has  a id from the column name that is in a second table. As  i have an array of Transacao, i don't know how to show the "name" because it's  from another Class type (Despesa).

```
public void Set_Refresh_Data() {
    contact_data.clear();
    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    ArrayList<Transacao> contact_array_from_db = db.Get_transacao();

    for (int i = 0; i < contact_array_from_db.size(); i++) {

        int tidno = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getId();
        String dia = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getDia();
        String mes = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getMes();
        String ano = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getAno();
        int idFrom = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getIdFrom();
        double valor = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getValor();

        Transacao cnt = new Transacao();
        cnt.setId(tidno);
        cnt.setDia(dia);
        cnt.setMes(mes);
        cnt.setAno(ano);
        cnt.setIdFrom(idFrom);
        cnt.setValor(valor);

        contact_data.add(cnt);
    }
    db.close();
    cAdapter = new Contact_Adapter(Main_Screen.this, R.layout.listview_row,
            contact_data);
    Contact_listview.setAdapter(cAdapter);
    cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}




public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        UserHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);

            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new UserHolder();
            holder.data = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_name_txt);
            holder.valor = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_email_txt);
            holder.idFrom = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_mob_txt);
            holder.edit = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_update);
            holder.delete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        user = data.get(position);
        holder.edit.setTag(user.getId());
        holder.delete.setTag(user.getId());
        holder.data.setText(user.getDia() + "/" + user.getMes() + "/"
                + user.getAno());
        holder.valor.setText("R$ " + String.valueOf(user.getValor()));
        holder.idFrom.setText(String.valueOf(user.getIdFrom()));
```

Comment: You have to make join query which give you data from both table and that value store in your arraylist it will defiantly work.

Comment: But when i add the data in a listview i get it from an array of Transacao, and how to get a field of another class?This i'm not understanding.